# App crashing on Droid X

Tags: java, android, android-version

I just built and released an app on TestFlight. However, when I tried to download -> launch the app on my phone it crashes right away.

My DroidX details are:

```
System Version: 45.621.10.MB810.Verizon.en.US
Android Version: 2.3.4
Kernel Version: 2.6.32.9-g3e80c7a
Build Number: 4.5.1_57_DX9-10
```

I tested my app on simulator that had the details below:

```
Device: Nexus 4
Target: Android 4.3 - API Level 18
```

How can I troubleshoot further to see why my app is crashing? On ADB I don't see options for DroidX in Device and neither do I see option for 2.3.4 under Target.

I'm new and trying to figure out where to go from here to find out why my app is crashing on this phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've built the app using an API that isn't available on the Droid X. As you noted above, the X is at Android 2.3.4, and your simulator is at 4.3.

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) for more information on setting the API in your app's manifest. Android 2.3 is API level 9.

Note, though, that if you downgrade the API your app is using, you won't be able to use features available in newer versions of Android. One of the most noticeable additions to Android since Gingerbread, for example, is the action bar.

If you do want to downgrade, you'll need to download and install the SDK for that API level to use it for development. The easiest way to do that is via the [SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html).

Comment: You are right. I finally connected the DroidX to my computer and ran the app to that device and now I can see the logs when the app crashes. The error is: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobile/com.mobile.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
` That sounds like something to do with action bar sherlock. Which, like you said isn't available on older versions?...

Comment: apparently I just needed to set the theme in my manifest and everything worked fine.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out; sorry I wasn't around for the follow-up.